# iPhone AudioSessionSetProperty

Tags: iphone

I got the below code from some example code.
What could possibly cause it to throw a CAXException?

I've loaded the AudioToolbox framework, am I missing anything?

Thanks,
Tee

UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_RecordAudio;
XThrowIfError(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category), "couldn't set audio category123!");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, need to call `AudioSessionInitialize` first.